# Wordpress and git, (using WPE), how do you incorporate database changes into the workflow?

Tags: git, wordpress

We use WordPressEngine and want to have multiple developers and multiple branches using git.

One challenge is how do we incorporate the database into the workflow? Should we take a sql dump and incorporate that in the commit?

Another challenge is due to the fact that WPE only gives you 3 environments. So, if developer A is tied to the staging, and developer B is tied to development, what would developer C use? (dont say production lol!)

Another interesting issue is when a feature on staging is complete. The WPE way of doing things is to copy one environment to another environment, like development to staging. Say I finished a feature in staging. All I would need to do is copy that environment to production and everything is done. How would I reflect this in git?

Im at the very beginning of researching this and even just writing this out is giving me ideas, but Id like to hear how others have approached this.